# Make table thead link change color and background image curve at both end

Tags: css

`a:active,a:link,a:visited{color:#06c}` control all the thead link color. How to overcome it without delete or change overall a color??

I have set `table thead th a {color: #ffffff;}`.

table thead actually have background image with radius left and right. How to make it shown?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNw62/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might add this to override link colors in your thead :

```
thead a:active, thead a:link, thead a:visited, a:hover {color: white;}
```

In order to make rounder corner be visible you should apply the style to the table, not the thead :

```
table {
    width:100%; height:29px; background:url('http://cdn2.f-cdn.com/img/bg/mod_top_blue1.png');
    -moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:10px; 
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the border-radius to the div containing the table and clip the overflow ... border-radius won't apply to tr, td, thead, table etc.

Example JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/sA4e8/2/)